# What type of damage is the desecration effect?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm attempting to build up some resistances for the higher difficulty and was wondering what type helps against the desecrator affix.

Comment: From my experience, you don't build up resistance to desecration zones, you avoid them. My monk is built for tanking and still gets destroyed by desecration if I stand in it at higher difficulty levels :)

Comment: I agree, that's the ideal situation but sometimes jailer/waller doesn't make that completely feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is physical damage:<sup>[[source]](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss_Modifiers#Desecrator)</sup>

> Desecrators create a "glowing void zone" beneath the feet of a character. These function like small Firewalls, dealing damage to any character who stands in them. The void zones do not move once cast, and can thus be avoided without great difficulty.
>
> - Monster Level Minimum: 22
> - Available to: Rare/Champion
> - Damage Type: Physical
> - Additional Resistances: None